# Deserialize JSON object xamarin C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, xamarin, serialization

I am getting the following error in Xamarin cross platform while deserializing the JSON Object. I have tried to do it with dictionary. But, everything gives me the same exception.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NBStudents.Models.jsonobjectclass+User]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.Path 'data.name', line 4, position 11.
```

My JSON Object Class:

```
public class jsonobjectclass
{
    public class User
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string current_group { get; set; }
        public List<UserGroups> user_groups { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserGroups
    {
        [JsonProperty("10")]
        public string Student { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("15")]
        public string Tutor { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("11")]
        public string Parent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Token
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public int expires_in { get; set; }
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }
    }


    public class UserResponse
    {
        public string msg { get; set; }
        public List<User> data { get; set; }
        public bool error { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Code to Deserialize JSON:

```
public static async Task<jsonobjectclass.UserResponse> UserRetrievalTask(string token, string apiUrl)
    {
        var jsonObject = new jsonobjectclass.UserResponse();
        string readHttpResponse;

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiUrl))
            {
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token); 
                using (var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    readHttpResponse = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var jObject = JObject.Parse(readHttpResponse);
                    try
                    {
                        jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonobjectclass.UserResponse>(jObject.ToString());
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        string excep = ex.ToString();
                        readHttpResponse = excep;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

My JSON String:

```
{{
  "msg": null,
  "data": {
  "name": "geoit",
  "email": "rokesh@geoit.in",
  "phone": null,
  "current_group": "11",
  "user_groups": {
   "11": "Parent"
   }
},
"error": false
}}
```

Please Help me to solve this.

Thanks,
Rokesh

Comment: post your json string

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]. All HTTP code is irrelevant, and the relevant part, namely the JSON string, is not in your question.

Comment: show us the value of readHttpResponse after you get the response

Comment: Added the JSON HTTP Response String..

Comment: That's not a valid JSON. Use an online validator to validate json.. https://jsonlint.com/https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: do u really have double braces like {{ }} or  {}

Comment: `request: 
Method: GET
Request headers send:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Accept-Language: da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7 [THIS IS JUST EXAMPLE, MUST BE ACTUAL] 
Response:
{"msg":null,"data":{"name":"User Name","email":"XX@xx.com","phone":"XXXXX","current_group":15,"user_groups":{"10":"Student","15":"Tutor"}},"error":false}`

Comment: Hi Jins, Double Braces like {{}}

Comment: this response has only 1??

Comment: The response you've shown in the comment doesn't have `{{`, so why does your post include that?

Comment: The http response String: `"{\"msg\":null,\"data\":{\"name\":\"geoit\",\"email\":\"rokesh@geoit.in\",\"phone\":null,\"current_group\":\"11\",\"user_groups\":{\"11\":\"Parent\"}},\"error\":false}"`

Comment: After this method, var jObject = JObject.Parse(readHttpResponse);  `{{
  "msg": null,
  "data": {
    "name": "geoit",
    "email": "rokesh@geoit.in",
    "phone": null,
    "current_group": "11",
    "user_groups": {
      "11": "Parent"
    }
  },
  "error": false
}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatch between the string and the object you are trying to deserialize into. The `data` object is not an array and there is an additional nested object which is not named in the JSON separately containing the `msg` field and the `user` data, but the `error` field is not part of that object:

As the comments have pointed out the JSON is not valid as is, so if you have control of the source I would fix that.

If not you could implement a reader and parse it as token by token, something like this:

```
using (var response = await client.GetAsync(_url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{

    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();      

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Start:
            // code to handle it
            break;
            case JsonToken.PropertyName:
            // code to handle it
            break;

            // more options 
        }
    }       
}
```

although this approach is more fragile. You can take a look at [The JSON.Net JsonToken docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonToken.htm) for more info.

Based on your comment and using https://jsonlint.com/ the response string

```
"{\"msg\":null,\"data\":{\"name\":\"geoit\",\"email\":\"roke‌​sh@geoit.in\",\"phon‌​e\":null,\"current_g‌​roup\":\"11\",\"user‌​_groups\":{\"11\":\"‌​Parent\"}},\"error\"‌​:false}"
```

is actually valid JSON, but the object is a little bizarre. I think it looks something like this in C#

```
public class UserGroup
{
    public string 11 { get; set; }
}

public class UserData {
    public string name  { get; set; }
    public string email  { get; set; }
    public string phone  { get; set; }
    public string current_group  { get; set; }
    public UserGroup user_groups  { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseObject
{    
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public UserData data  { get; set; }
    public bool error  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow...!! It really worked for me thanks buddy... :-)

Comment: The token approach or the C# objects? Event though it is valid JSON / C# POCOs I can't help but think that the source is not serializing properly. Having a property of "11" is just weird

Comment: Yeah the main thing is I should use the class object `public UserData data  { get; set; }` instead of List array `public List<UserData> data  { get; set; }` ... Great!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It should be an array the opening and closing brackets should be square brackets:

**[**

```
{ "msg": null,"data":
```

**[** {
          "name": "geoit",
          "email": "rokesh@geoit.in",
          "phone": null,
          "current_group": "11",
          "user_groups":

**[**{
           "11": "Parent"
           }
**]**

}
**]**,

"error": false
        }

**]**

Also in your code, you dont need `var jObject = JObject.Parse(readHttpResponse);` since the `readHttpResponse` is already a JSON string which you can deserialzie into an object.

Comment: This Line `readHttpResponse = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` gives me output as `"{\"msg\":null,\"data\":{\"name\":\"geoit\",\"email\":\"rokesh@geoit.in\",\"phone\":null,\"current_group\":\"11\",\"user_groups\":{\"11\":\"Parent\"}},\"error\":false}"`

Comment: This Line `var jObject = JObject.Parse(readHttpResponse);` gives me `{{
  "msg": null,
  "data": {
    "name": "geoit",
    "email": "rokesh@geoit.in",
    "phone": null,
    "current_group": "11",
    "user_groups": {
      "11": "Parent"
    }
  },
  "error": false
}}`

Comment: So How to change the outer {} to []...??

Comment: Try directly deserializing the `readHttpResponse` directly instead of using JObject.Parse

Comment: Do you mean I should give like this, `jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonobjectclass.UserResponse>(readHttpResponse);`

Comment: Wrong. The data object inside the JsonResponse is the issue. It needs to be array

Comment: @Rokesh - yes try that first.

Comment: Same Error Buddy.. :-( `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[NBStudents.Models.jsonobjectclass+User]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.`

Comment: let me just cook a fiddle with your json.

Comment: Ok so here's what I found out so far, the Newtonsoft is complaining because the nested objects in the json string is not written as an array. Here's a fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/8c5i0t) to better visualize your issue, there are two variations that returns a JSON string, `sampleGoodJson` is the fixed version, and `sampleBadJson` is actually based on your original json string. You'll notice there that the array inside must still begin with [ ], the bad one does not have { }.

Answer (score 0):

Aplogies for the misleading answer earlier. The object you need to make array is the 'data' property of the response JSON. You have to get it from the server side as your Domainmodal `List<User>`. You should get a better understanding from this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/icMJCK)

`readHttpResponse` can be

```
    {
          "msg": null,
          "data": [{
          "name": "geoit",
          "email": "rokesh@geoit.in",
          "phone": null,
          "current_group": "11",
          "user_groups": {
           "11": "Parent"
           }
        }],
        "error": false
   }
 and
```

`readHttpResponse.data` needs to be array

```
[{
              "name": "geoit",
              "email": "rokesh@geoit.in",
              "phone": null,
              "current_group": "11",
              "user_groups": {
               "11": "Parent"
               }
            }]
```

Comment: I am receiving it as a {{}} only @Jins. Because I don't have access to the server.. Is there a way to change the outer {} to [] in the code??

Comment: You dont have access to server? You can suggest the server guys to make it array if your expected result requires an array.

Comment: Ya the Senior Developer gave me only the request url and JSON methods.

Comment: Is that response object an array or set of objects to be shown in the client?? or is it always gonna need one object

Comment: Only one object will be the output

Comment: Try this answer. this will work remove the unnevessary JObject.Parse too